# When is the number of Divisors of a Number equivalent to one of its Factors?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

My math teacher asked me this problem for homework and I am unsure how to solve it.

Which numbers contain a number of factors equivalent to the value of one of their divisors?

I found that 8 works, because it has 4 factors and 4 divides 8, but I did that by manually computing the number of factors of each number. I am unsure how to develop a  general process of proof to find all such numbers.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A033950](https://oeis.org/A033950)

Answer (score 2):

You're asked to solve $\sigma_0(n)|n$, with $\sigma_0$ the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Definition). Luckily, $\sigma_0$ is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function). Writing an arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$ as $\prod_ip_i^{a_i}$, with the $p_i$ finitely many distinct primes and the $a_i$ positive integers, $\sigma_0(n)=\prod_i(a_i+1)$, so $n$ qualifies iff each $a_i+1$ is a product of powers of the $p_i$. Since once you choose which prime factors you want the legal choices of the $a_i$ are thereby specified, that's about as elegant an all-solutions characterization as you'll get.